# React Native Vector Icons

Tags: react-native, mobile, frontend, icons, react-native-vector-icons

I am working on developing a mobile app and want to add a react native vector icon component. The problem is that the icon is not showing up--it seems to be invisible. It know it is there because it is influencing a nearby element that shares the same flexbox.

Here are the imports:

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, Text, View, Pressable } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { styles } from "./styles";
```

And here is the specific place in my code where I'm introducing the Icon

```
<Icon name="checkbox-outline" size={40} color='black'/>
```

As well as the broader "Post" function in which it's used

[postFunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdfXd.png)

To give some context, this function is for a "post" that one would see on a "feed". Think of Twitter or Instagram.

Here is also a screenshot of what the result looks like when this post function is called multiple times. Notice that the Icon should be showing up at the bottom left corner of each post. And the button (which has row flex of 1) is not covering the entire width indicating the Icon is present but not visible.

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8uMj.png)

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

after installing [React-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons),
you must always run this command :

> react-native link

otherwise the icons will not appear

Comment: I'm using Code Sanbox, an online IDE. So I don't know if I'm really installing React-native-vector-icons. Do I run this command after I add it as a dependency?

Comment: I've never used that IDE  , but its may like Snack , but that i know after adding a dependency you need to run  a `react native link` , to link the folder that containe the icons to yours project

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but where do I run the command? There's not really a command line since it's online...